# no border around DIV

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to be able to fade one image into another on hover and then fade out the hovered image once the mouse leaves the object. Because its tightly packed within a DIV i do not want any space around it, so was trying to use just SPAN which is not working. Any idea?
 MY scripts are the following:

```
<style>
.fade {
          position: relative;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
        }

        .fade div {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          display: none;
          height: 100px;
          width: 240px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
        }
-->
</style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    $(function () {
        // find the div.fade elements and hook the hover event
        $('span.fade').hover(function() {
            // on hovering over find the element we want to fade *up*
            var fade = $('> div', this);

            // if the element is currently being animated (to fadeOut)...
            if (fade.is(':animated')) {
                // ...stop the current animation, and fade it to 1 from current position
                fade.stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
            } else {
                fade.fadeIn(250);
            }
        }, function () {
            var fade = $('> div', this);
            if (fade.is(':animated')) {
                fade.stop().fadeTo(3000, 0);
            } else {
                fade.fadeOut(3000);
            }
        });
    });

    //-->
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<span class="fade">
        <img src="theImages/sApproveBW.jpg" alt="Who we are" />
        <div>
            <img src="theImages/sApprove.jpg" alt="Who we are" />
        </div>
    </span><img src="theImages/bApprove.jpg" height=100 width=240 /><br><img src="theImages/tApprove.jpg" height=100 width=240 />
```

I have a little white space below the first image. Anyway to get rid of it?

How it looks: http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/7417/imgct.png

I want to get rid of the white space in between the first image on top from the image thats green.

my New HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Fade Method 1 (two images)</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    <!--
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
        img { border: 0;
display: block;
}

.fade {
    position: absolute
        }

        .fade div {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          display: none;
          height: 100px;
          width: 240px;
        }

    -->
    </style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    $(function () {
        // find the div.fade elements and hook the hover event
        $('span.fade').hover(function() {
            // on hovering over find the element we want to fade *up*
            var fade = $('> div', this);

            // if the element is currently being animated (to fadeOut)...
            if (fade.is(':animated')) {
                // ...stop the current animation, and fade it to 1 from current position
                fade.stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
            } else {
                fade.fadeIn(250);
            }
        }, function () {
            var fade = $('> div', this);
            if (fade.is(':animated')) {
                fade.stop().fadeTo(3000, 0);
            } else {
                fade.fadeOut(3000);
            }
        });
    });

    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body id="page">
    <span class="fade">
        <img src="theImages/sApproveBW.jpg" alt="Who we are" />
        <div>
            <img src="theImages/sApprove.jpg" alt="Who we are" />
        </div>
    </span>
<img class=t src="theImages/bApprove.jpg" height=100 width=240 />
<img class=t src="theImages/tApprove.jpg" height=100 width=240 />
</body>
</html>
```

But now i have two images, the second one(green) went under the first one(black) and the third one(yellow) is right below the black one. 
Here is the example: http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/9557/imgdu.png

Comment: Bad idea to use `DIV` inside a `SPAN`

Comment: I was trying to avoid the DIV all together but then it seems the fade script does not work.

Comment: set display block on your img tag

Comment: interfaithmedical.com/testdir/test.html you notice how the black one disappeared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img {
    display:block;
}​​​​
.fade div {
    margin-top:-100px !important;
}
```

Remove the `top:0px; left:0px;` and add the above code and that should sort it out.

Comment: they are three different images. I want one to come below another so they are lined up one beneath the other. no matter what position i put them in, the black(first) image comes right above the green image(second)

Comment: There's four.. if it's because it's overlapping, it's because you have `position:absolute;`

Comment: http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/9557/imgdu.png you see how the green image went underneath the black image?

Comment: I think this would help if we could actually play with the images.  Do you have them hosted anywhere?  The JS fiddle doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: yes you are right, hold on please. let me see if i can upload it somewhere.

Comment: Not sure what was going on with what i was doing but Titanium, your JSFIDDLE link did the trick, after minor adjustment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding: `display:block` to each image and it should work

I eddited your code a bit but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/nTCr4/16/

Comment: http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/9557/imgdu.png thats what it looks like after i edited above.

Comment: Now add `position: relative` to your images

Comment: i did add the position:relative, the black image disappeared.

Comment: interfaithmedical.com/testdir/test.html you notice how the black one disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

BTW, your issue with space and images is doe to your images are naturally aligned inside the parent element, to prevent that you can use for your images the CSS property: `vertical-align:middle;` That will fix it. But here's another example:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ovivey/4/edit)*

All you need is this HTML:

```
<div class="fade">
  <img src="" alt="" />  
  <img src="" alt="" />  
</div>
```

this CSS:

```
 div.fade {
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    width:240px;
    height:100px;
}
div.fade img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

AND jQ:

```
  var imgTwo = $('.fade').find('img:eq(1)');
  imgTwo.hide();
  
  $('.fade').hover(function() {
    imgTwo.stop().fadeTo(300,1);
  },function(){
    imgTwo.stop().fadeTo(3000,0);
  });
```

Comment: @Interfaith read my edit at the top of my answer. `vertical-align` is what you was looking for (not positionings, margins or anything - like suggested elsewhere). But I gave you another example with a simpler jQuery code and HTML and CSS markup. Pick your choice.